# Macro to open a delimeted text file in Text format

Tags: excel, vba

I have to covert delimeted .txt  text files to excel files. Using below code i am able to covert the files

but all the numeric values are saved with discarded zero.  ( "00001112" saved as "1112").

is there a option to enbale to open a text file in excel text format.

My code:

```
TxtFile = txtFldrPath & "\" & Left(CurrentFile, Len(CurrentFile) - 4)
      Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TxtFile, _
      origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=True, _
      Comma:=True
```

Number of columns in each text file is differs ,

Please help me on achiving this.

thanks.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keep-leading-zeros-in-number-codes-HA010342581.aspx ... is your problem reading the csv or trying to preserve when you write one?

Comment: @Mr.Monshaw - problem is while writting the sql output to csv it is not preserving the preceeding zero's. I need to know is there a option to write the output is textformatting.

Answer (score 0):

Not answer but suggestions.

Excel does that automatically to predict what data type it should store and remove unnecessary details such as spaces and leading zeros. Workaround is what to do after text imported.

1. Change the formatting of the columns so it displays leading zeros, or
2. Change the value to Sting after the formatting

Something like `.Cells(R,C).Value = Format(.Cells(R,C).Value, "00000000")` in a loop.